# Merging Multiple lists into a singular list format

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good evening,
I am trying to create a singular list from multiple different lists, but when i merge them it just gives me `[listA], [ListB]` instead of `ListA, ListB` i dont know how to explain so ill just show what i have tried and show my expectation.

here is my original code.

```
N, B, E = "N", "B", "E"
data = [N, N, N, N, N, N, N, 
        N, N, N, N, N, N, N, 
        N, N, N, B, E, N, E,
        N, N, N, N, B, E, N,
        B, B, B, B, B, B, B,
        N, E, N, B, N, N, N]
```

and when i print `data` i get the  result

`['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'B', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'B', 'E', 'N', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'B', 'N', 'N', 'N']`

thats what i want to happen, but i quickly realised i would not be able to edit it easily in this format. so i tried making 6 different lists and converting them into one.

```
N, B, E = "N", "B", "E"
Data6 = [N, N, N, N, N, N, N]
Data5 = [N, N, N, N, N, N, N]
Data4 = [N, N, N, B, E, N, E]
Data3 = [N, N, N, N, B, E, N]
Data2 = [B, B, B, B, B, B, B]
Data1 = [N, E, N, B, N, N, N]
```

So that is my base, i tried 2 ways to merge them but both of them proved unsuccessful, after googling around for a while i still got nothing

my 2 attempts where:

```
data = [Data6,
        Data5,
        Data4,
        Data3,
        Data2,
        Data1]
print(data)
```

```
data = []
data.append(Data6)
data.append(Data5)
data.append(Data4)
data.append(Data3)
data.append(Data2)
data.append(Data1)
print(data)
```

im expecting the result that i get from the pre created list but instead i get
`[['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'], ['N', 'N', 'N', 'B', 'E', 'N', 'E'], ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'B', 'E', 'N'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['N', 'E', 'N', 'B', 'N', 'N', 'N']]`

If anyone knows how to help or what i am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `data.extend()` ?

Comment: Simply use `+` to concatenate your lists. For example `data = Data1 + Data2`

Comment: `itertools.chain` : https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20chain#itertools.chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `+` operator for lists.

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [5,6,7,8]
print(l1+l2)
>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

This operation is called **concatenation**.

What you want for your problem is :

```
data = Data6 + Data5 + Data4 + Data3 + Data2 + Data1
```

Comment: Same as my comment

Comment: You posted roughly when I was writing so I didn't have time to check :)

Comment: That's fine, don't worry. I just want to say, we have the same answer, same thinking. So, let me vote up your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

use sum with init value []

```
data = sum(data, [])
```

or build like this:

```
data = [*Data6, *Data5, *Data4, *Data3, *Data2, *Data1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need to concatenate the lists :

```py
    DATA = Data6 + Data5 + Data4 + Data3 + Data2 + Data1
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are inserting lists inside a list. This operation simply puts a pointer to the list A into list B. So you end up having a list B which contains pointers to another lists.
You can use concatenation (+) or array.extend() as Rakesh suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use extend like this

```
N, B, E = "N", "B", "E"

Data6 = [N, N, N, N, N, N, N]
Data5 = [N, N, N, N, N, N, N]
Data4 = [N, N, N, B, E, N, E]
Data3 = [N, N, N, N, B, E, N]
Data2 = [B, B, B, B, B, B, B]
Data1 = [N, E, N, B, N, N, N]

data = []
data.extend(Data6)
data.extend(Data5)
data.extend(Data4)
data.extend(Data3)
data.extend(Data2)
data.extend(Data1)

print(data) # Output : ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'B', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'B', 'E', 'N', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'N', 'E', 'N', 'B', 'N', 'N', 'N']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run a for loop over the contents of data1,data2 and Soo on , and just push the elements

Since you are pushing all the list , therefore they ouutput is as list of list

New_list = [*data1, *data2 ] and Soo on , new method in python3.6

Comment: not good if there are MANY items in at least one of the list. If you want to add 3 elements to a list of 5000 elements it's not effective to loop 5003 times

Comment: You could just append it* to list by running 3 times to add only3 items, y running it for 5000 times*

Comment: what if the first list has 3 items and the second has 5000 ? what if you have 10 lists ? are you gonna check and sort them by length ?

Comment: No I ain't gonna sort them*

It is same as 
data1 + data2 + ... , I have just told him the underlying thing, that how to add list 
To prepare a new list you have to iterate over all the elements

Answer (score 0):

To make it efficient, you can use `for` loop to concatenate the list. No matter how many lists you want to concatenate, you don't need to write one by one.

```
N, B, E = "N", "B", "E"
Data6 = [N, N, N, N, N, N, N]
Data5 = [N, N, N, N, N, N, N]
Data4 = [N, N, N, B, E, N, E]
Data3 = [N, N, N, N, B, E, N]
Data2 = [B, B, B, B, B, B, B]
Data1 = [N, E, N, B, N, N, N]

data = [Data6,
        Data5,
        Data4,
        Data3,
        Data2,
        Data1]

new_data = []
for dt in data:
    new_data = new_data + dt
print (new_data)
```